# Бот не отправляет сообщение в лс (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот, discord.py

есть вот такой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def g_token(ctx, us):
    loc = os.getcwd()
    author = ctx.message.author
    a = str(author.id)
    memid = us[3:21]
    user = bot.get_user("676013712917659648")
    await user.send('TEST!')
```

и он полностью работает!

но если вместо `user = bot.get_user("676013712917659648")` вставить  `user = bot.get_user(memid)`
он не отправляет сообщение в лс

если кто-то не понял, `memid = us[3:21]` из <@!id>  делает id

добавив  debug line: `print(us, type(us))` получил вот такой ответ:
`<@!676013712917659648> <class 'str'>`

а добавив вот такой debug line: `print(memid)` получил ответ:
`676013712917659648`

и если попробовать вывести `user` оно ответит: `None!`

PS: Человек с таким id есть на сервере

Comment: подозреваю что дело в типе данных, но не знаю как решить эту проблему

Comment: А точно ли us содержит именно то, что вы ожидаете? Попробуйте в самом начале функции добавить print(us, type(us)) и добавьте в вопрос, что будет выводить такая команда.

Comment: да, я проверял до этого, но добавил в вопрос то что выводит данная команда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `us`, как я понял, упоминание пользователя. (`!g_token @User#1234`), то Вы можете добавить аннотацию для аргумента, чтобы преобразовать в тип [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User), а потом вызвать метод [`await send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.send).

```py
@bot.command()
async def g_toke(ctx, user: discord.User):
    loc = os.getcwd()
    author = ctx.message.author
    a = str(author.id)
    ...
    await user.send('TEST!')
```